# Excel - How to reset the default Table name when copying a sheet with a table

Tags: excel, vba, rename, listobject, excel-tables

I have a workbook with one worksheet `Sheet1`. On that Sheet I have one table with its default name `Table1`.

When I copy the worksheet `Right-Click` > `Move` or `Copy` in the same workbook I get sheet `Sheet1 (2)`.

The Table on this sheet is automatically named `Table13`.
I do some processing in that copied sheet and subsequently remove it. Leaving the workbook with only its original `Sheet1`.

Each time I make a copy of `Sheet1` the table in the copied sheet is incremented by one.
Also if I remove the sheet and add a new one. It keeps incrementing.

I use the workbook and `Sheet1` as a template and I create via a macro a lot of copies.

The new Table Name has now Incremented to `Table21600`.
I found out that Excel will give an overflow when I reach approximately `Table21650`.

So, I need a way to reset the Name counter of the added table.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access (and alter) the names of each table ("ListObject") from your macro-code as shown in this example:

```
Sub ListAllListObjectNames()

Dim wrksheet As Worksheet
Dim lstObjct As ListObject
Dim count As Integer

count = 0
For Each wrksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lstObjct In wrksheet.ListObjects
        count = count + 1
        lstObjct.Name = "Table_" & CStr(count)
        Debug.Print wrksheet.Name, ": ", lstObjct.Name
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reset Table 'Counter'

- Allthough the 'counter' will not stop incrementing, when you close
  the workbook and open it the next time, it will again start from
  `Table13`.
- In the `Immediate` window <kbd>CRTL+G</kbd> you will see the table name
  before and after the renaming. When done testing just out comment the
  lines containing `Debug.Print`.

**The First Code**

```
' Copies a sheet and renames all its tables.
Sub CopySheetWithTable(Optional SheetNameOrIndex As Variant = "Sheet1", _
  Optional NewTableName As String = "Tbl")

    Dim MySheet As Worksheet
    Dim MyCopy As Worksheet
    Dim MyTable As ListObject
    Dim i As Long

    Set MySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetNameOrIndex)
    'MySheet.Copy MySheet    ' Before e.g. Sheet1)
    MySheet.Copy , MySheet  ' After e.g. Sheet1
    Set MyCopy = ActiveSheet
    For Each MyTable In MyCopy.ListObjects
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print "Old Table Name = " & MyTable.Name
        MyTable.Name = NewTableName & i
        Debug.Print "Old Table Name = " & MyTable.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

**Usage**

- Copy the previous and the following sub into a module. Run the
  following sub to copy a new worksheet. Adjust if you want it before
  or after the sheet to be copied.
- You don't need to copy the worksheet manually anymore.

**The Second Code**

```
' You can create a button on the worksheet and use this one-liner in its code.
Sub CopySheet()
    CopySheetWithTable  ' Default is CopySheetWithTable "Sheet1", "Tbl"
End Sub
```

**Delete all Sheets After Worksheet**

This is just a testing tool.

```
' Deletes all sheets after the selected sheet (referring to the tab order).
Sub DeleteSheetsAfter(DeleteAfterSheetNameOrIndex As Variant) 'Not tested.

    Dim LastSheetNumber As Long
    Dim SheetsArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' Try to find the worksheet in the workbook containing this code.
    On Error Resume Next
      LastSheetNumber = _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DeleteAfterSheetNameOrIndex).Index
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There is no Sheet '" & DeleteAfterSheetNameOrIndex & "' " _
          & "in (this) workbook '" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ThisWorkbook
        ReDim SheetsArray(.Sheets.Count - LastSheetNumber - 1)
        For i = LastSheetNumber + 1 To .Sheets.Count
            SheetsArray(i - LastSheetNumber - 1) = i
        Next
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetsArray).Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    MsgBox "Deleted " & UBound(SheetsArray) & " worksheets after worksheet '" _
      & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DeleteAfterSheetNameOrIndex).Name & "'.", _
      vbInformation, "Delete Successful"

End Sub

Sub DeleteAfter()
    DeleteSheetsAfter "Sheet1"
End Sub
```